# SQL return parent name if parent ID exists, else return current name in select query

Tags: sql

Thanks in advance, I have a table that includes a parent ID if the item has a parent tied to it. I am trying to figure out a way to select the name from the parent if the id is present and if it isn't, then select the current name all in one select statement.

Example:

A product table:

```
id |Name     |ParentId 
1  | Hello   | null
2  | Goodbye | null
3  | Allo    | 1
```

I would like to try to find a way doing getting back something like this:

```
id |Name     |ParentId 
1  | Hello   | null
2  | Goodbye | null
3  | Hello   | 1
```

Again thank you in advance. I have been trying to get something like this to work for a while now.

Comment: you could use COALESCE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `LEFT-JOIN` (actually self-join since it joins to the same relation) with `COALESCE()` function to take the first non-empty column value

```
select t.id, 
       coalesce(p.name, t.name) as pname, -- parent name if present, otherwise product name
       t.parentid
from product t
left join product p on t.parentid = p.id
```

Try above query and adjust the select list to meet your needs. Consider adding a different column with `COALESCE` result rather than replacing the current name of a product with name of its parent since it can be confusing for the receiver.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a self join and `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT p.id, COALESCE(p2.Name, p.Name), p.ParentId
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product p2 ON p.ParentId = p2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using `case`-`when`:

```
select case child.ParentId is null
       when 1 then child.name
              else parent.name
from products child
left join products parent
on child.ParentId = parent.id
```